# Sharepoint 2007 Page Redirection Issue

Tags: c#, sharepoint, isapi-rewrite

I have an issue in Sharepoint 2007. Can someone please suggest a solution for the same. Below is the issue.

1. We have a sharepoint site and it redirects to `"sitename"/pages/default.aspx` by default. So my first task is to stop this redirect and just display the sitename without `pages/default.aspx` in the URL.
2. If the users are typing `sitename/pages/default.aspx`, we also need to make the redirect of `sitename/pages/default.aspx` to `sitename`

I am able to solve point 1 using ISAPI Rewrite 3 tool. But when I use the same tool for point 2, I am getting circular reference error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the rules you have now, but please try to use the following ones:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^pages/default\.aspx$ /? [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ /pages/default.aspx [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the Reply, i have added the rewrite rules that u suggested and could not find any difference.
I have added 
RewriteRule ^/pages/default\.aspx$ /? [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ /pages/default.aspx [NC,L] and still i am getting circular reference error.

The Rewrite rule i used to stop redirection to /pages/default.aspx is
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename$
RewriteRule ^/$ /Pages/Default.aspx